# TreeView vs. ListView MouseDown (long-press) Event Sequence Code-Execution-Pause Difference

Tags: excel, vba, listview, events, treeview

This is an Excel VBA Project (because someone edited the title) and I need to clarify what this post is about.

I am writing code that walks/works through VBA Code Modules to list procedures as well as controls on UserForms and list how/what procedures call each other.

I was trying to simulate jiggling of a userform control, **at run time**, on a Userform in the VBA Editor's Designer window, to notify the user that this particular control, was selected, with the mouse on the ListItem/Node of ListView/TreeView on a modeless userform.

It's complicated to describe in words, so I attached a GIF.
[image: ListView MouseDown+ItemClick]
In the GIF, it can be seen, in the Immediate pane, that code execution paused after executing the **MouseDown and ItemClick** events in the ListView, because I didn't release the pressed Left Mouse Button (LMB).
So I guess the sequence of events in ListViews is like:

1. MouseDown
2. ItemClick
   **Pause**
3. MouseUp
4. Click.

And, thus, I put my jiggle routine code in ItemClick event of the ListView.

However, when I try to do the same thing with TreeView, I found that the code execution paused right after MouseDown event of the TreeView, if I didn't release the LMB, without going on to execute the NodeClick event, as it did with ListView and it's MouseDown Event.

Since I placed my jiggle code in TreeView NodeClick event handler, which has not occured yet, there was no jiggle effect.
But upon release of the LMB, the control's jiggle effect was quite immediate for the eye to catch, as the code execution continues after the pause at the end of MouseDown event, nonstop, up to the end of MouseUp Event.
This sequence of events can be seen in the Immediate window's output as shown in the GIF below.
[image: TreeView MouseDown+NodeClick]
It is also evident here that the code execution paused after MouseDown event was handled, if the left mouse button was held down, **without** going on to NodeClick Event, as it did in ListView.

1. MouseDown
   **Pause**
2. NodeClick
3. MouseUp
4. Click.

So, the situation was laid out as above.
I tried to place the jiggle code into the MouseDown Event.
However, since I need the SelectedItem from the TreeView to get my jiggle code working, it's like I needed the NodeClick Event anyway.

I tried to examine the SelectedItem/selected-Node of the TreeView in the MouseDown Event but unfortunately, it only returned the previous SelectedItem/selected-Node rather than the Node on which the MouseDown Event just occured, which makes sense in itself, because SelectedItem is not yet set to new Node as NodeClick Event has not occured yet.

I thought that if only I can get the Node under the mouse at the time of MouseDown Event by using HitTest, I could use that Node as the SelectedItem in my jiggle code.
Another obstacle arises, in that, the TreeView HitTest function uses X,Y as Singles which appear to be in ?Twips rather than Pixels, I may be required to use magic numbers=88,90 and the magical TwipsPerPixel function and recalculate it for different monitors and resolutions.
So, I searched for a different solution.

**PS:Being a Myanmar, I have a duty to promote awareness that there's a Revolution occuring right now in Myanmar against a cruel military coup and would like to plead you guys to please support the people of Myanmar. Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

I found the different solution in the form of a custom-made HitTest function, using the SendMessage API call to the TreeView, rather than using the TreeView's default HitTest function, available [here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/comctl/tvcheckbox.htm).
The code sample there, was allowed to be used freely but not to be published on any website as mentioned in their copyright disclaimer.
So I guess I cannot share the code snippet here but I believe it's ok to share the link to that site.

I had to modify, the code mentioned there, a bit, to return the Node but not the handle to the Node as returned in their function.
I used that function because it uses Pixels as X,Y coordinates rather than the ?Twips that VBA uses.
Similar function for ListViews can also be found elsewhere if one googles hard enough.
So, it works like a charm and the control is jiggling now, inside the MouseDown Event, without using NodeClick event.
[image: TreeView MouseDown]
I think that the bottom line here, is:

- ListViews and TreeViews differ in handling mouseclick events in that ListViews seem to consider ItemClick Event as part of the MouseDown Event sequence and TreeViews consider NodeClick Event as separate from MouseDown Event
- I have no idea about the reasoning behind this but suspect that it may be in their origins

I wrote up this Question+Answer post to help fellow VBA programmers with the ItemClick vs. NodeClick Event sequence discrepancy and also to let them know that there is a better HitTest routine out there, which can be used without having to convert mouse coordinates in pixels.

This whole VBA project is part of my VBA Project Info tool (with Code Obfuscator and Visual Codeflow tools) with the barebone-basic Alpha RC version available on [GitHub](https://github.com/NLYinMaung/VBA-Project-Information).

***Remarks:*** I cannot, for the life of me, find the official description of MouseClick Event sequences of ListViews and TreeViews anywhere. Thus, had to resort to `debug.print "1.TV_MouseDown"` stuff.

***PS:Being a Myanmar, I urge y'All to please support the Myanmar Spring Revolution.***
**Vive la Myanmar Révolution!!!**